# Downsampling possible within RTSP/RTP?

Tags: h.264, rtsp, rtp

I have a media server serving several cameras.
I'd like for the server to downsample the data from, say, 20 fps to 1 fps.
Obviously I could do this by decoding and recoding the video frames - however, the server is a little resource constrained. I notice that if I simply drop RTP UDP packets, the output is not so good - I see both tearing and junk in the images (at least with a opencv/ffmpeg client).

Is it possible to downsample within an RTP stream by dropping more carefully chosen frames/packets, to avoid junk and tearing in the output? (Currently I'm able to extract RTP|H264 raw data chunks on the server, but am not running them through a full codec).

Answer (score 1):

An H.264 stream consists of different frame types: I (or IDR), P and B.

I (or IDR) frames are a full pictures and can be decoded without any other frames.

So you could filter out P and B frames and only pass on I frames.

Your resulting frame rates depends on the I (or IDR) frame frequency of the original stream. I am guessing you get somewhere between 0.1 to 2 fps.